# Is there any way to automatically adjust OS specific environment variables, path, etc. format?

Tags: vim9, vim9script

Often in my scripts I have some ugly snippets like the following:

```
vim9script
var bin = ""
if has("win32")
    bin = "\\bin"
else
    bin = "/bin"
endif

g:path_with_bin = g:path .. bin
```

The same happens when it comes to environment variables since they are expressed as `$MY_VARIABLE` syntax in OSX and Linux systems and `%MY_VARIABLE%` in Windows (at least when using `cmd.exe`).

I am wondering if there are functions that recognise the OS and prevent us to explicitely use conditionals, something like

```
g:path_with_bin = g:path .. adjust_slashes(bin)
```

that sets slash-backslashes automatically depending on the OS, or, for environment variables, something like the following:

```
env_var_set(MY_VARIABLE, value)
```

which set `$MY_VARIABLE` or `%MY_VARIABLE%` to `value` depending on the OS.

Comment: All that typing instead of a simple `:h env<C-d>`…

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about what you want to achieve? I believe there are numerous cases where you can use the Unix syntax on both Linux and Windows. The exception being creating a some Windows command line statement but here also Windows accept very often the Unix syntax. An example would be helpful.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt nothing more and nothing less than what I described: setting paths and environment variables. That is all. I accepted your answer as it solved both of my problems. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For environment variable you can use within Vim the Unix syntax:

```
:echo $foo
let $foo = 'bar'
```

For the path I believe you can also use the Unix syntax (`/` separated path) for all the Vim API.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if this works for `:let $PATH = …` to convert `/` in `…` on Windows? I don't have a Windows machine to test

Comment: Vim will not convert but Windows will make the best of a path containing `/` instead of `\`. The only problem I see is that the dos command don't accept path containing `/` since they are interpreted as options. But if you are making dos command in a Vim script I suppose you should encapsulate it in `if has('win32')` anyway.